# Replace a substring match with regex using C++

Tags: regex, c++14

I use std::string regex_search and std::string regex_replace to find the substring and replace. My problem is that I don't know how to express it by my regular expression. When it comes to yy->%y the other case such as y, yyy,yyyy,yyyyy,etc..-> %Y

```
std::string text = "y yyaa";
std::regex y_re("[yY]+"); // this is the regex that matches y yyy or more yyyy
std::regex yy_re("(?=^y{2}[^y])y{2}"); // this is the regex that matches only yy- my problem is here
std::string output = "";
smatch m;

if (regex_search(text, m, yy_re)) {
    output = std::regex_replace(text, yy_re, "%y");
}
else {
    output = std::regex_replace(text, y_re, "%Y");
}
cout << output << endl;
```

My actual output :

```
%Y %Yaa
```

My expected output :

```
%Y %yaa
```

Comment: You have shown the expected output, but what is the *actual* output?

Comment: And have you tried experimenting with the regular expressions om some site like https://regex101.com? Something like that could help you understand the expressions and what they do better.

Comment: Why is the expected output `%Y %ya` and not `%Y %yaa`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I did some but still can't do it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, it's my bad. I have edited the post.

Comment: So, try https://ideone.com/650laJ then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may play it safe and use more specific regex patterns to match 1) single `y` or `Y` or 3 or more `y`/`Y`s, or 2) only two `y`/`Y`s:

```
std::string text = "y yyaa";
std::regex y_re("([^yY%]|^)[yY](?![yY])|[yY]{3,}"); // this is the regex that matches y yyy or more yyyy
std::regex yy_re("([^yY%]|^)[yY]{2}(?![yY])"); // this is the regex that matches only yy- my problem is here
std::string output = "";

output = std::regex_replace(text, yy_re, "$1%y");
output = std::regex_replace(output, y_re, "$1%Y");
std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

See the [online C++ demo](https://ideone.com/650laJ).

You may use this approach even when the order of replacements is not known.

**Regex details**

- [Regex 1 matches](https://regex101.com/r/fD35xC/2) only a single or 3 or more consecutive `y` / `Y`s:

  - `([^yY%]|^)[yY](?![yY])` - Group 1: start of string or any char other than `y`, `Y` and `%`, then a `Y` or `y` and then no `y` nor `Y` is allowed
  - `|` - or
  - `[yY]{3,}` - three or more `y` / `Y`s

Regex #2 works similarly, just `[yY]{2}` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/fD35xC/4) only two `y` or `Y` chars.

The replacement contains a backreference to the Group 1 value to put back the captured char.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my code. If my `text = "yytyya"` the expected output should be `%yt%yaa`, right?? But the actual output is `%y%yaa` it give away the character `t`. Do you think the problem is with `regex_replace`??

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm You are not using `$1` in the replacement, see [it is working fine](https://ideone.com/FDNNNO)

Comment: Yeah, it is. What is $1 in the replacement? Can you help me with that too? I don't understand.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm ***The replacement contains a backreference to the Group 1 value to put back the captured char.***